# Elements overlapping on send mod message page

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, responsive-design, moderator-messages

In case of unverified Email for user, the private mod message has overlapping between page title and the notice on narrow screen:

> [image]

Link for test for staff: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/message/create/-1

Related report on ModTeams: https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/moderators/a/6616/825